# How to simulate app kill using either espresso or uiautomator?

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

We have a app that has some data stored in singleton classes. so, the data changes only after the app is killed. so,We have a usecase that require app kill in the middle of automation testing. How to simulate kill the app and reopening the app

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you kill the app with adb command during test is running, your test will crash.

You can use

```
device.apps.kill(your_app_name)
```

and please check the permission FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES was added

Also we are using next steps:

```
private val uiDevice: UiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
uiDevice.pressRecentApps()
uiDevice.findObject(your_app_name) and swipeUp or swipeLeft for killing
```

You can use the following to launch the application:

```
val packageName = getContext().packageName
device.apps.launch("$packageName")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response and sorry for the late reply. What does the device means in `device.apps.kill(..` and `device.apps.launch(...` .apps is not referenced in UiDevice...

Comment: Hi. Sorry, this is sample with Kaspresso. https://github.com/KasperskyLab/Kaspresso.  Kaspresso is a framework for UI testing, which based on Espresso and UI Automator.

Comment: I have this https://gist.github.com/Venkat-juju/1cdc013c14930f46ea4f204186fbfa69 test on my app.. but it doesn't seems to be killing the application... it just does nothing